# Modal dialog de angular material no abre al presionar un botón pero al recargar si

Tags: angular, modal, angular-material

Quiero abrir un modal al momento de presionar un botón en una lista con registros de una bd mongo, pero al presionar el botón no me abre el modal, ni siquiera entra al método, pero al hacer un refresh y presiono el botón nuevamente, si que ejecuta el método y muestra el modal, que puede estar sucediendo?

**Componente del modal:**

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Install Angular</h2>

<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
    <p>Este es un cuadro de dialogo</p>  
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Install</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

**Método que llama al modal e importación del modal:**

```js
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ModalBedComponent } from 'src/app/components/modal/modal-bed/modal-bed.component';

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { 

  }

openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalBedComponent);

    console.log("metodo dialog")

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
```

**Component.html que llama al método para abrir el modal:**

```html
<tbody *ngIf="patientss">
  <tr *ngFor="let patient of patientss; index as i">

      <button (click)="openDialog()" class="btn btn-info">
          <i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Agregar Cama
      </button>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Importaciones de angular-material**

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GCH - Gestión Camas Hospitalarias</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/images/favicon.png">

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: nose si es un typo en la pregunta pero en `Component.html` te falta el tag para abrir `<td>`

Comment: no, no es eso el problema